# Kivy : Move image following mouse movement without kv

Tags: kivy

I want to move a image following mouse movement.
Especially, I'm at a loss how do I get mouse movement amount and translate coordinates.

I tried `to_local` , `to_window` , `to_parent` but I could not get it well...
Here is my minimal code. How should I modify this?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class TestLayer(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {'top':1, 'x':0}
        self.size_hint_x = 1
        self.size_hint_y = 1

    def build(self):
        # specify your image dir and name
        self.img = Image(source='0.png', size=(100, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.img)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'left':

                # Hold value of touch downed pos
                pass

        return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'left':

                # self.img.x = self.img.x + (mouse movements distance)
                # self.img.y = self.img.y + (mouse movements distance)
                pass

        return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'left':

                # process after movement or something?
                pass

        return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layer = TestLayer()
        self.add_widget(layer)
        layer.build()

sm = ScreenManager()

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is set up in the correct way. What you need to do is save where the mouse was at each touch event (`touch_down` or `touch_move`) and compare to where it is now. Then you take the difference of those two, and move your image by that much.

The `x` and `y` coordinate of a touch are in the `touch.pos[0]` and `touch.pos[1]` variables respectively.
For example:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        if touch.button == 'left':

            # Hold value of touch downed pos
            self.last_touch = touch.pos # Need this line
    return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

and

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        if touch.button == 'left':
            self.img.x = self.img.x + touch.pos[0] - self.last_touch[0] # Add the x distance between this mouse event and the last
            self.img.y = self.img.y + touch.pos[1] - self.last_touch[1] # Add the y distance between this mouse event and the last
            self.last_touch = touch.pos # Update the last position of the mouse

    return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_move(touch)
```

Comment: It worked!! I misunderstood that the problem is difficult...haha. It's so simple. Thank you so much.