# Movable button with collision boundary

Tags: python, mobile, kivy

I'm working on a module for a larger Kivy app. Within some layout, I want to contain some menu buttons and a container. In the container there are `ButtonBehavior` "Points" which use a small circular image. These points should be able to be dragged around the screen, updating some x-y position stored within them. Points should only be moved by touch inputs that collide with the point itself.

I've been working on trying to override `collide_point`, but I'm running into some issues, and I think I'm just misunderstanding the fundamentals of some of the pieces I'm working with.

I'm trying to make something like this:

1. Some arbitrary layout that contains all the following, plus possibly a menu.
2. Some `ScatterLayout` for containing an arbitrary and dynamic number of Points.
3. Some Point which can only be moved within the layout, but has it's own collision.

Am I understanding `ScatterLayout` correctly? Does the layout need to be sized to encompass the full space in which its widgets can be moved, or does the `ScatterLayout` just need to fit around the point, and then it itself can be moved around within the arbitrary layout containing it?

Additionally, I'm trying to stick to writing out most of this in straight Python using Kivy's library, rather than put it in .kv syntax.

Comment: An example of moving an image (works for any widget, really) is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622239/kivy-move-image-following-mouse-movement-without-kv/54634867#54634867

Comment: I tried setting up the code from that question, and found it seems to have the issue I'm running into. I want to have my collision only occur within the bounds of the image itself. That is, if the image is a 30 by 30px square, it should only be moved if the user clicks within that square, after which it can be moved anywhere within a layout, then be movable only if the user clicks where it now is. This is still helpful in some respects, but I'm still a bit confused!

Comment: Ah, I see. Well the code from that question definitely will help you. Right now, the `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_move` functions are defined inside the class that refers to the whole layout. So if you click anywhere in your screen, it'll move the button. You need to define the functions in a class for your button. Then when the functions refer to `self` it'll reference the button and not the widget. So `self.collide_point` will check if the mouse is within the button rather than in the overarching layout / screen. I can post an answer with an example if you have trouble, but try it yourself!