# Kivy Navigation Control

Tags: python, kivy

I was wondering whether it is possible to make a Navigation control just like the one in GIMP using the kivy framework in python

Navigation Control: This is a small cross-shaped button at the lower right corner of the image display. Click and hold (do not release the mouse button) on the navigation control to display the Navigation Preview. The Navigation Preview has a miniature view of the image with the displayed area outlined. Use the Navigation Preview to quickly pan to a different part of the image—move the mouse while keeping the button pressed. The Navigation Window is often the most convenient way to quickly navigate around a large image with only a small portion displayed. (See Navigation Dialog for other ways to access the Navigation Window). (If your mouse has a middle-button, click-drag with it to pan across the image).

Refer to point 11 on this link : https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-window.html
And : https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-navigation-dialog.html

Comment: Yes that is possible but there isn't any sort of standard widget to do it. You'd need to implement it yourself, probably using features like `on_touch_down` on the navigation control widget to open navigation control, `on_touch_move` inside the navigation control image to pan the image (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622239/kivy-move-image-following-mouse-movement-without-kv/54634867#54634867). This will be a fun project, but don't expect it to happen in 30 mins! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually helps quite a lot.